# Warning: missing space before text for line 7 and 10 of jade file

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Is there something wrong about the format of jade?

```html
   1. doctype html
   2. html
   3.     head
   4.          script.
   5.             function submitData() {
   6.                 var obj={
   7.                  firstname:document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value,  ***`<---7 line --->`***
   8.                    username:document.getElementById("txtUserName").value
   9.              };
  10.           var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();   <--lines 10 here
                xhr.open('post','/',true);
                xhr.onload = function(e) {
                if(this.status == 200){document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=this.response;}
                };
                xhr.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
            }
```

Comment: You should add your script to an external script file and reference that instead of writing it inline, you will avoid this issue.

Comment: Good answer and it indeed solved this problem,thanks a  lot!